# WebRTC Android - gclient sync error in Windows

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle, apprtc

I'm trying to work out the instructions defined in [http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android](http://WebRTC%20Android). After the command "**gclient sync**" is executed and after hours of downloading, at the end the process failed:

```
fatal: early EOF
The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 924, in _Clone
        self._Run(clone_cmd, options, cwd=self._root_dir, retry=True)
      File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 1201, in _Run
        gclient_utils.CheckCallAndFilterAndHeader(cmd, env=env, **kwargs)
      File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 293, in CheckCallAndF
    ilterAndHeader
        return CheckCallAndFilter(args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 538, in CheckCallAndF
    ilter
        rv, args, kwargs.get('cwd', None), None, None)
    CalledProcessError: Command 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=512m clone --no-che
    ckout --progress --verbose https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git C:
    \\webrtc_android\\src\\chromium\\_gclient_src_x3yrqm' returned non-zero exit sta
    tus 128 in C:\webrtc_android\src\chromium
    ----------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 2325, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 2311, in main
    return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
  File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\subcommand.py", line 252, in execute
    return command(parser, args[1:])
  File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 2066, in CMDsync
    ret = client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
  File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 1523, in RunOnDeps
    work_queue.flush(revision_overrides, command, args, options=self._options)
  File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 1024, in run
    self.item.run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 834, in run
    file_list)
  File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 166, in RunCommand
    return getattr(self, command)(options, args, file_list)
  File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 418, in update
    self._Clone(revision, url, options)
  File "C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 932, in _Clone
    if os.listdir(tmp_dir):
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\webrtc_a
ndroid\\src\\chromium\\_gclient_src_x3yrqm/*.*'
Error: Command 'C:\\depot_tools\\depot_tools\\python276_bin\\python.exe -u src/s
ync_chromium.py --target-revision 47ce5feb1d13ce889da15f76f063a7978a0b5c37' retu
rned non-zero exit status 1 in C:\webrtc_android
Hook ''C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe' -u src/sync_chromium
.py --target-revision 47ce5feb1d13ce889da15f76f063a7978a0b5c37' took 77717.11 se
cs
```

Does this has to do with the fact that I'am trying to execute it on Windows?

Comment: Here is a step-by-step instruction in my personal blog on how to build WebRTC stuff for Android: http://andrii.sergiienko.me/?go=all/building-webrtc-demo-for-android/ - Hope, it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independently of your error, you will not be able to fetch and compile code for android under windows. You need to be on the right linux distribution.